# How to add additional requestMatchers in multiple SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Lets assume I am adding some security in Spring Boot 3 using the `SecurityFilterChain` `@Bean` multiple times.

The first `@Bean` looks as follow:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
        .requestMatchers("/api/core/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

While the second `@Bean` is supposed to add **additional `requestMatchers`**

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainAdditional(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
        .requestMatchers("/api/module2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

Unfortunately, the second method `filterChainAdditional` is correctly called in the expected order.
**But it does not extend the `requestMatchers`**.

Even more curious in the second bean all `requestMatchers` seem to be unavailable in the `HttpSecurity` context.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this probably?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple security filter chains? You could use only one filter chain.

Comment: Project is build up modular. So a module may provide additional `requestMatcher`

Comment: As dmitriys already wrote, there is no way to merge it out of the box, you have to implement it by yourself. dmitriys' answer is a nivce workaround. Every module needs its own  URL sub path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand. `SecurityFilterChain` beans do not merge `requestMatchers` they just execute matched filters.

Option that may work (didn't check):

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher("/api/core/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/api/core/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
    
    return http.build();
}
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainAdditional(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher("/api/module2/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/api/module2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: I only notice a differences in the response status, when an endpoint does not exists while using `securityMatcher`. Instead of HTTP Status 403 I now get HTTP Status 404 Not found

Comment: I was porting an application from Spring Boot 2 --> 3 and ran into this problem.  I had two `SecurityFilterChain` `@Beans` configured, but using the `@Order` annotation.  SB3 ignored this ordering and sent all requests to the 1st `SecurityFilterChain` - this prevented any of the form login stuff from running since everything was denied.  I removed the `@Order` annotation on both beans and added `.securityMatcher("/api/core/**")` to the first one - this then allowed the browser initiated requests to hit the 2nd `SecurityFilterChain`.